# After clicking submit button the details entered by user has to be shown in another registration form

Tags: javascript, html

I created a HTML Registration page using HTML5 and Javascript its worked but after clicking submit button i have to show the details entered by the user in the another registration form (which is hidden on the same page before clicking submit button). once u have clicked submit button then that registration form has to be shown and the details which we entered also has to be shown.

Comment: If the user is directed to a new page, the answer depends on what server side programming language you use, but likely it will be contained in GET or POST. If the user is not directed to a new page, just write some javascript.

Comment: Better display form data on next page where values are passed..

Comment: the user is directed to other page but data is not obtained by the form from another form.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in first page fields with name "field1", "field2", "field3" etc
like -

```
<form action='page2.html'>
<input type='text' name='field1'> 
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

In page2.html, get the parameters of GET request by javascript.
You can print the form values by using the function `get(parameter)` like - `get("field1");`

```
    <script>
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
</script>
In page1, you entered
<script>
 document.write(get("field1"));
</script>
```

You can see it working [here](http://ezone.host-ed.me/page1.html)
But it is always better to use server side programing like php jsp asp etc. if you want to keep record for the fields and use it

Comment: i want to display the data in the textfield,textarea,checkboxes which are present in the second page similar to that of first page..

Comment: supppose your textfield have id "id1" in page 2, then do document.getElementById("id1").setAttribute("value",get("field1")); in javascript

Comment: If try it without seeting it to textbox i'm getting result but while setting the value to textbox i'm unable to get result.

Comment: my text field contains "name" not contains "id" then what is the syntax for this??

Comment: document.getElementsByName("id1")[0].value